# how to send selected dropdown value to controller using Onchange and ajax post call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is what I tried so far.
I'm able to get ID using onchange

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TestID").change(function() {
        debugger;
        var TestSampleID = $(this).val();
        $("#TestID").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/MyController/MyAction?iTestID=" + TestSampleID,
            contentType: "html",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#hds").append(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
        })

    })
});
```

```html
@if(ViewBag.TestData != null) {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestID, ViewBag.TestData as SelectList, new {
        @class = "form-control", @required = "required"
    })
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MyAction (int iTestID)
    {
        
     ///My Action
        
    }
```

but my ajax post call is not working i.e.. not sending selected value to my action.

Comment: I try your code, and I can get iTestID in the action. Try to use `F12` to see if you get any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo you can refer to it.

Testmodel:

```
public class Testmodel
    {  
        public int TestID { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

MyControllerController:

```
 public class MyControllerController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var TestData = new List<Testmodel>()
            { new Testmodel(){TestID=1,Name="a"},new Testmodel(){TestID=2,Name="b"}  };
          
            var CountriesItems = TestData.Select(q => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = q.Name,
                Value = q.TestID.ToString()
            });
            var model = new Testmodel
            {
                Countries = CountriesItems
            };
           
            ViewBag.TestData = CountriesItems;
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult MyAction(int iTestID)
        {

            return View();

        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model Testmodel

@if(@ViewBag.TestData != null) {
    
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestID, new SelectList(Model.Countries,
"Value", "Text"), "Select country", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
}
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TestID").change(function() {
        debugger;
        var TestSampleID = $(this).val();
        $("#TestID").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/MyController/MyAction?iTestID=" + TestSampleID,
            contentType: "html",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#hds").append(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
        })

    })
});
</script>
```

result:

[image]